# Synchronized method calling another synchronized method which calls wait()

Tags: java, synchronized

What if a synchronized method calls another synchronized method (in another class), which does wait(). Will the lock be released in the first synchronized method as well, although being in another class?

E.g.

```
    public class A {
        private B b;

        public A(B b) {
           this.b = b;
        }

        public synchronized String a() {
           return b.b();
        }
   }

    public class B {

        public synchronized String b() {
            while (!someCondition) wait();
            return "Success!";
        }
    }
```

So my question is, will it be possible to enter another synchronized method in A during the time someCondition = false? Or does wait() just make it possible to enter other synchronized methods in B while an attempt to enter another synchronized method in A will fail until a() returns?

Comment: No, it will only release `B`, see: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/nested-monitor-lockout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. While invoking `a` and subsequently `b`, no other method can enter neither `a` or `b` (or any other synchronized method of classes `A` or `B`). `b.wait()` however releases the lock on all synchronized methods on `B` since

```
public synchronized String b()
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
public String b() {
   synchronized(this) {
    ..
   }
}
```

Comment: But the wait()-call in b will release the lock in class B, right? So if we would have another method in B e.g. public synchronized c(), it would be possible to enter c, when wait() has been done. Right?

Comment: But then it wouldn't even be possible to release the lock in A from method b(), since a() is locked on "this" as well?